# Compare a series of numbers by their location

Tags: bash, count, compare, series

I need to check the utilization of the GPUs connected to my PC and if one goes lower than the threshold count it, my script runs in loop every 10 seconds and check utilizations

> UTILIZATIONS=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu
>   --format=csv,noheader,nounits)

That gives an output like this for 6 gpu

> 99 100 98 100 97 98

```
COUNT=6 
THRESHOLD=95
GPU_COUNT=$(nvidia-smi -i 0 --query-gpu=count --format=csv,noheader,nounits)

for UTIL in $UTILIZATIONS
    # If utilization is lower than threshold count them:
    if [[ $UTIL -lt $THRESHOLD ]]
    then
    COUNT=$(($COUNT - 1))
    fi
```

Problem is it count all and not one by one, I need it to check and compare each GPU utilization to its own previous value and count like this
GPU_N_COUNT=$((GPU_N_COUNT - 1 ))

So if 3rd GPU utilization goes Bellow threshold for 6 times the GPU_3_COUNT = 0 or the first one that hit 0 makes COUNT=0 either works.

Comment: use shell arrays like `gCount=( $(nvidia...) ) ; echo "gCount=${#gCount[*]}" ` . Good luck.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gCount, can you please explain more, or give an example ?

Comment: I have renamed your variable `GPU_COUNT` to `gCount` The `${#gCount[*}}` notation prints the number (`#`) of elements in the specfied array, i.e. `${arrName[*]}`. So maybe `if [[ ${#gCount[*]} -lt $threshold ]] ; echo "OK" ; fi` gives you some ideas.Good luck.